Evolution & iCloud calendar - Cannot edit events
I followed the directions here to add my iCloud calendars to Evolution 3.44 on Ubuntu 22.04. Mostly this works, with the following (fairly important) exception:
If I add an event to my iCloud calendar using my iPhone, and if that event has other attendees listed, I see the following message when I attempt to edit the event in Evolution: "Changes made to the event will not be sent to the attendees, because you are not the organizer." I have tried to edit events anyway, and changes are indeed not reflected on my iCloud calendar.
In these cases, the organizer field of the meeting popup does not show my iCloud email address. Instead, it shows something like, "My Name </[a long string of seemingly random characters and numbers; not hexadecimal]/principal/>"
Has anyone else encountered this? Is there a known soluation? Searching the internet and Askubuntu has not yet yielded a solution.
Thank you.
